# symbols not shown in taskbar

Tags: unity, taskbar

I use ubuntu 11.04.

In my taskbar no extra symbols are shown like for skype or vuze but instances still run in background ( ps -e in terminal shows them).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem - it is a configuration setting.

Updated as per your comments:

Ahhh - I guess you have the newest format by default. If you want those icons you need to start Unity in 'Classic' mode.

The alternative is to follow the instructions at [Ubuntugenius](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/ubuntu-11-04-fix-show-all-iconsindicators-in-unity-panels-notification-area/), the simplest version being to type this in a terminal:

- gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"

and then refresh Unity

Comment: Hi Rory, the right-click does not work in the taskbar (the bar on the top) and even in the launcher (bar which is left in unity). In the taskbar for example the wlan smybol, clock and loudspeaker is shown but no skype or vuze for example.. What can I do else to show the symbols of such applications?

Comment: I mean the symbols in the notification area

Comment: HI Rory.  now the symbols are shown. Thank a lot for your help

Comment: Excellent - if that solved your problem, click on the tick to the left of my answer to accept it, so others with the same issue can find the answer easily.